# Multiple interface implementation in Exceptions - JMockit

Tags: junit, jmockit

Iam very new to JMockit and i have a scenario where i have two mock objects created for different interfaces in same Exceptions anonymous class. Is this possible to mock two interfaces and its implementations in same exceptions class.? Have given the example code snippet below -

```
public class MockInterface {

@mocked 
TestADao daoA;

@mocked
TestBDao daoB;

@Test
public void test() {
 new Exceptions() {
 {
  doaA.sampleTestA(argA, argB)
  TESTA objA = new TESTA();
  returns(objA);

  doaB.sampleTestB(argC);
  TESTB objB = new TESTB();
  returns(objB);
 }

 };
 assserNotNull(objA);
 assertNotNull(objB);
}
```

Is it possible to mock like this.?
Any help will be greatly appretiated

Comment: Yes, it's possible, using an `Expectations` block just like the example code shows. What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Thanks for the response. When i tried using the above mentioned code it is injecting only one DAO, that is the one given first.